# How to add multiple eventhandler to same html element and do exeecute different method according to event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to execute different functions on a HTML element according to the event handler, for example if I click on the p tag its background should turn to red but if I double click something else should happen. I did it initially but with many bugs like if I triple click then the function to be executed by single click it runs, but the double click method works fine. Is there any better solution to fix it?

What I initially did was something like this :

```
//Event 1 

var p = document.getElementById("textNode");


p.addEventListener('dblclick', function init() {
   //some code
}, false);

// Event 2

var element = document.getElementById("textNode");

element.addEventListener('click', elemEventHandler, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-click-and-dblclick-example/)

You can easily merge them to a single element by using a timeout.

```
<script>

    var click = 0;
    var t = undefined;

    function doclick (click)
    {
        if (click == 1)
        {
            console.log('click');
            $('#textNode').slideUp();
        }
        else if (click == 2)
        {
            console.log('dblclick');
            $('#textNode').fadeOut();
        }
        clearTimeout(t);
        delete window.t;
    }

    $(document).ready(function()
    {

        $('#textNode').click(function()
        {
            clearTimeout(t);
            delete window.t;
            t = setTimeout('doclick(1);', 500);
        });

        $('#textNode').dblclick(function()
        {
            clearTimeout(t);
            delete window.t;
            t = setTimeout('doclick(2);', 400);
        });


    });

</script>

<body>
    <p id="textNode">TEST</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using both the `click` and `dblclick` events on the same element is a bit tricky, because in order to double click you have to click and click again, so it's no bug that the (single) click handler fires.

If you really want to use both, you should `setTimeout` (few hundred milliseconds) for the click event handler, and then `clearTimeout` if the dblclick handler fires. So you'll be delaying the click event handling a little bit to check for dblclick. You'll need to decide how you want to handle triple clicks etc.

But overall, I don't think using both click and dblclick is common practice in web dev. You might want to think about a better alternative.